# Using jquery full calendar with MVC4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am learning MVC and jquery but I have a view and I can get that to load but it is blank.

I am trying to get a basic calendar using the `jquery-fullcalendar`.

I will post my view code and see what I maybe doing wrong.

*update* I have tried to use fullcalendars sample code and still it never renders anyone know why?

```
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
          // put your options and callbacks here
      })
  });
</script>

  <div id='calendar'></div>
```

I know I am just missing something but I just can't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else has this problem I am using **Telerik** for the **menus** and in the layout there is this code

@(Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().DefaultGroup(group =>            group.Combined(true).Compress(true)))
           @(Html.Telerik().StyleSheetRegistrar().DefaultGroup(group => group.Add("telerik.common.css").Add("telerik.windows7.css").Combined(true).Compress(true)))

These where in the **body** and i just moved them to the head it does not seem to have affected the menus but did fix the full calendar and started to render it

Answer (score 0):

Using the "basic" template I would remove the jquery script tag from the view. When I create a new MVC4 project in VS2012 the _Layout.cshtml looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

The line @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") puts the jquery script tag after the body of your view. You can change your view so that it renders the fullcalender.js and your document ready function after the jquery script tag like this

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
@section scripts {
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/fullcalendar.css")"rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/fullcalendar.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type ='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({});
        });
    </script>
}
<h2>Index</h2>

<div id='calendar'></div>
```

Comment: Thank for the information I did have that in the layout so i replaced the view with the code you gave but still no calendar. I will keep trying things to see if i can get this fixed.